# Why are attempts to predict the future as abhorrent as Molech worship?

Tags: avodah-zarah, sorcery-magic-kishuf, latid-lavo-future

[Devorim 18 (10, 11)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.18.10?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) lists in possukim 9 & 11 the following activities as תוֹעֲבֹ֖ת (abhorrent practices):

1. consigns a son or daughter to the fire,
2. or who is an augur,
3. a soothsayer,
4. a diviner,
5. a sorcerer,
6. one who casts spells,
7. or one who consults ghosts or familiar spirits,
8. or one who inquires of the dead.

The abhorrence of practice 1, Molech worship, is clear.

**My question is why are attempts to predict the future equally abhorrent?**

I see [here](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/4372130/jewish/The-Tragic-History-of-Molech-Child-Sacrifice.htm) that

> Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch opines that the link between  sexual
> promiscuity and Molech worship is that “one’s children are not born
> from blind bodily lust but were rather born inherently free. So too in
> their lives, they should not be subservient to **blind luck and
> destiny which befalls them.** After all, their conception and birth
> were by Divine Guidance and Providence, and therefore they should lead
> a purposeful life… “Give Me your children – says G‑d – let Me educate
> them, allow Me to bring each one of them to their ultimate potential
> in their unique way. Don’t give them over to Molech and thereby
> desecrate My name!” *(my emphasis)*

Maybe not being subservient to **blind luck and destiny** establishes the link between predicting the future and Molech worship. In other words it is the wish to predict the future which is the abhorrent element!

Comment: "“one’s children are not born from blind bodily lust but were rather born inherently free" what doe these things mean?

Comment: My understanding is: one might think that if children were simply the product of natural processes without “Divine Guidance and Providence” they might be subjected to the constraints of “blind luck and destiny” which can be predicted through those forbidden methods of predicting the future. But they are **free** from those constraints because of the hashgocho ( Divine Guidance and Providence).

Comment: They are all in the same category, but not equal in severity or punishment.